# How and where can I apply logs to check that a JSON file gets loaded when a web page in browser is loaded?

Tags: json

How and where can I apply logs to check that a JSON file gets loaded when a web page in
browser is loaded?

I am using the browsers :- Firefox / Internet Explorer

In which code or file would I have to apply the "console.log"?

My page is a static one.